# How can selenium run in IE do not show the browser windows?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

The operating system is windows10, the programming language is JAVA ,the browser is IE11. How can selenium running without the browser windows?

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but on Linux it helps to start a dedicated X server and start the tests in there. Could you do something similar, for example using VNC or RDP?

Comment: Try out this. http://triflejs.org/ It uses PhantomJS underneath which is a famous headless browser (Phantom is supported by Selenium). I haven't tried it out though.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to use triflejs in selenium?

Answer (score 2):

You can use phantonjs, HtmlUnitDriver or headless chrome

For HtmlUnitDriver

```
WebDriver driver=new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

For phantomjs first download ghostdriver and use

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "E:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs.exe");  
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();   
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

For chrome download the Chromedriver and use

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a headless browser like phantomjs, htmlunit to run with selenium webdriver.